# Use Robo 3T to connect to remote MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nginx, ssh, digital-ocean, robo3t

I'm trying to use Robomongo (or Robo 3T) under Mac to control my mongodb in the remote Ubuntu & Nginx server.

Normally, I need to `ssh xxx.xx.xx.xx` in a terminal with a username and a password to connect to the server. in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb.io`, there is `listen 443 ssl`.

In Robo 3T, I tried to set up the connection with `Use SSH tunnel`. I tried the port number `443` or `80`. But it gave me an error: `Error: Resource temporarily unavailable. Error when starting up SSH session: -13. (Error #35)`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try connecting without SSH Tunnel and SSH runs on port 22(in case you haven't changed it but you should change it).

Comment: If I connect without SSH Tunnel, which way should I use?

Comment: Just uncheck the SSH Tunnel and try to connect.

Comment: I filled the port with 22, unchecked the SSH Tunnel, it gave me an error: `Cannot connect to the MongoDB at :0. Error: Network is unreachable.`

Comment: This means the SSH Connection went through but wasn't able to connect to your MongoDB instance. Try checking on your server whether Mongo is running or not.

Comment: My server is always ON. By the way, what should I enter in `Address` under `Connection` tab of Robo 3T?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159275/discussion-between-shubhamoy-chakrabarty-and-softtimur).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct setting is

1) under `SSH`, check `User SSH tunnel`, use port `22`

2) and under `Connection`, write `127.0.0.1:27017`

Answer (score 6):

I've done few configurations on my Ubuntu 18 Vagrant box in order to successfully connect MongoDB remotely using Robo 3T GUI. I've explained in the following steps.

1. On Ubuntu server, to open mongo shell run:

   ```
   $ mongo
   ```
2. Inside mongo shell, type following command to create new a admin user.

   ```
   > use admin;
   > db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"password", roles:[{ role: "root", db: "admin" }]});
   ```
3. By default mongodb is configured to allow connections only from localhost(IP 127.0.0.1). We need to allow remote connections from any ip address. The following change should only be done in your development server. Open up  **etc/mongod.conf** file and do the following change.

   ```
   # network interfaces
       net:
           port: 27017
           bindIp: 0.0.0.0   #default value is 127.0.0.1
   ```

Also in the same **mongod.conf** file uncomment security option and add *authorization* option as shown below.
`security: authorization: enabled`

4. Save and exit the **mongod.conf** file and restart mongodb server.

   ```
   $ sudo service mongod restart
   ```
5. Download and install Studio 3T GUI tool from https://robomongo.org.
6. On Studio 3T GUI, in the connection settings, you need to do few changes as shown on
   below screen shots.

[image]

Enter mongodb **admin** database username and password which you have created earlier.

[image]

Here, I have entered my Ubuntu 18 Vagrant box ssh credentials.

[image]

Save the changes and press *connect* icon to see if the connection is working fine.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for my purposes. Just to clarify for other users--the config file is in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Comment: You have a typo, **service** but not "servcie"

Answer (score 3):

Connect to remote `MongoDB` using [Roto3t](https://robomongo.org/download)

Firstly, we should check the standard [URI connection scheme](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)
for `mongodb`

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

We make a `SSH Connection` to the remote `MongoDB` on [Cloudfoundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/)

in my case
`cf ssh -L port_forwarding:HOST_NAME:Port NAME_OF_APP`

(1) In the `Connection` tab in `Robo3T` we choose

```
Type: direct connection
Name: choose_any_connection_name
Address: localhost and port is 'port_forwarding' we choose in the SSH connection we made.
```

(2) in the `Authentication` tab, we should add `database`, `username`, `password`, and `Auth Machanism: SCRAM-SHA-1`

(3) in the `SSH` Tab we will uncheck `use SSH tunnel` as we made it manually.
Now, if you click test the connection should be successfully done.

**Note**: If we use [Studio 3T](https://robomongo.org/download) it will parse the URI and fill all these fields for us.